# Allowing links from user's input - safety

Tags: php, javascript, xss, code-injection

I want to link what starts with `http(s)://` in user's input.

```
$ui = htmlspecialchars($ui, ENT_QUOTES);
$ui = preg_replace("/(https?\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\_\+\@\&\-\#\/\%\?\=\~\|\!\:\,\.\;\(\)]+)/", 
"<a href=\"\\1\">\\1</a>", $ui);
```

Is this code safe or there still is a possibility to inject javascript? I could add some 'blacklist filtering', eg. to forbid "javascript:" phrase, but it seems it makes no sense, as there are [too many things to cover](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html).

Comment: tried FILTER_VALIDATE_URL? http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Comment: You know, you don't need to escape characters inside charsets, except technically `-`, but not even that if you put it at the end.

Comment: @elclanrs I know, IMO it's better to escape them - as in this case - you forgot about `/`, which has to be escaped also. Anyway, that's not the subject.